# recursively find the longest increasing sequence in array in java

Tags: java, arrays, recursion

for example this is array [1, 4, 9, 2, 6, 7, 3, 5, 8, 10]. and 1,2,3,5,8,10 is the answer

so how can i solve this with recursion.

thanks for any help.

```
public class 4b {

   public static int getLongetsLadder(int[] array){
   int i=0; 
   int[] result = recursive(array,i); 

   return 0; 
   }
   public static int[] recursive(int[] array, int i)
   {
   return null;
   }


   public static int[] recurse(int  i, int arr[])
   {
       int[] answer = new int[1];
       answer[0]= arr[i];

       return answer;

   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Implement ion in Java is given below:

```
public static Integer[] recurse(int i, int li, int arr[]) {

    if(i == arr.length)
        return new Integer[0];

    boolean choice = (li == -1) || arr[li] < arr[i];
    /* now you have choice to choose it or skip it */
    if(choice) {
        /* choose it */
        ArrayList<Integer> l = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        l.add(i);
        for(Integer v : recurse(i + 1, i, arr)) {
            l.add(v);
        }

        /* dont choose it */
        ArrayList<Integer> r = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        for(Integer v : recurse(i + 1, li, arr)) {
            r.add(v);
        }

        /* return largest */
        return l.size() > r.size() ? l.toArray(new Integer[0]) : r.toArray(new Integer[0]);
    }

    /* skip and proceed */
    return recurse(i + 1, li, arr);
}
```

Thats how it should be called:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    findLargest(1, 4, 9, 2, 6, 7, 3, 5, 8, 10);
}
public static void findLargest(int ... vals) {
    Integer[] longest = recurse(0, -1, vals);
    for(Integer i : longest) {
        System.out.println(vals[i]);
    }
}
```

Result of above call was `1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 10`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working example ready to run.
It's based on the idea that on each step, you try either including the current item in the search for an increasing sequence (only if it passes the condition of actually being bigger than the last item), or excluding (ignoring) the current item out of the sequence.
That way you get the recursion to cover all available paths.

*IntList.java*

```
public class IntList {
    private IntNode _head;

    public IntList() {
        _head = null;
    }

    public IntList(IntNode node) {
        _head = node;
    }

    public int longest() {
        return longest2(_head,0);
    }

    public int longest(IntNode current,int max) {
        if (current.getNext() == null)
        {
            if (current.getValue() > max)
                return 1;

            return 0;
        }

        int with, without;

        without = longest2(current.getNext(),max);

        if (current.getValue() > max) {
            with = 1 + longest2(current.getNext(), current.getValue());
            return Math.max(with,without);
        }

        return without;
    }
}
```

*IntNode.java*

```
public class IntNode {
    private int _value;
    private IntNode _next;

    public IntNode(int val, IntNode n) {
        _value = val;
        _next = n;
    }

    public int getValue()     {
        return _value;
    }

    public IntNode getNext()  {
        return _next;
    }
    public void setValue(int v)  {
        _value = v;
    }
    public void setNext(IntNode node)  {
        _next = node;
    }
}
```

*Main.java*

public class Main {
        public static void main(String[] args) {

```
        IntNode n1 = new IntNode(3, null);
        IntNode n2 = new IntNode(5, n1);
        IntNode n3 = new IntNode(10, n2);
        IntNode n4 = new IntNode(5, n3);
        IntNode n5 = new IntNode(1, n4);
        IntNode n6 = new IntNode(4, n5);
        IntNode n7 = new IntNode(2, n6);
        IntList list = new IntList(n7);
        System.out.println("should be 4, is: " + list.longest());


        IntNode n11 = new IntNode(7, null);
        IntNode n21 = new IntNode(6, n11);
        IntNode n31 = new IntNode(5, n21);
        IntNode n41 = new IntNode(4, n31);
        IntNode n51 = new IntNode(3, n41);
        IntNode n61 = new IntNode(2, n51);
        IntNode n71 = new IntNode(1, n61);
        IntList list2 = new IntList(n71);
        System.out.println("should be 7, is: " + list2.longest());

        IntNode n12 = new IntNode(10, null);
        IntNode n22 = new IntNode(5, n12);
        IntNode n32 = new IntNode(5, n22);
        IntNode n42 = new IntNode(1, n32);
        IntNode n52 = new IntNode(1, n42);
        IntNode n62 = new IntNode(4, n52);
        IntNode n72 = new IntNode(2, n62);
        IntList list3 = new IntList(n72);
        System.out.println("should be 4, is: " +list3.longest());

        IntNode n13 = new IntNode(7, null);
        IntNode n23 = new IntNode(4, n13);
        IntNode n33 = new IntNode(3, n23);
        IntNode n43 = new IntNode(1, n33);
        IntNode n53 = new IntNode(8, n43);
        IntNode n63 = new IntNode(5, n53);
        IntNode n73 = new IntNode(1, n63);
        IntList list4 = new IntList(n73);
        System.out.println("should be 4, is: " + list4.longest());
    }
}
```